# generate all binary numbers of a given length that have an even number of 0's and 1's

Tags: python-3.x, binary

I'm wondering the most performant way to generate every binary number of a given length that has an even number of 0's and 1's. I'm currently doing it in a brute force way and generating strings, which I assume is a rubbish way of doing it:

```
def max_bits(b):
    return (1 << b) - 1


def binary_options(digits):
    target = digits / 2
    return [f"{i:b}" for i in range(max_bits(digits - 1), 2 ** digits) if f"{i:b}".count("0") == target]
```

I'm using the binary number as an index to sum all possible combinations of an array split into two even halves, so I don't actually need to store the combinations, I can sum as I go, and I also don't need the binary numbers as strings. See below for an example.

```
arr = [1,2,3,4]

comb1 = 1001 # 1 + 4 and 2 + 3
comb2 = 1010 # 1 + 3 and 2 + 4
comb3 = 1100 # 1 + 2 and 3 + 4
```

Many thanks.

Edit:

Apologies for not mentionining this earlier, but I don't need to generate the inverse of a solution, so I only need half of the potential permutations. For instance, in the above example I have `1001`, `1010` and `1100` but not `0110`, `0101` or `0011`.

Edit2:

The best solution was provided by Mark. To generate only half the binary numbers (as I don't need inverses) I use the funciton below. I'm also storing the binary numbers as integers, not strings, and using the bits of the integers as indexes using the method provided in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16660062/11192010).

```
def binary_options(digits):
    target = digits / 2
    return [i for i in range(int('1' * (digits - 1), 2)) if i.bit_count() == target]
```

Comment: Do you count leading zeros?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If using Python 3.10+, [`int.bit_count()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#int.bit_count) is available:

```
>>> for i in range(16):
...   print(f'{i:04b}, count={i.bit_count()}')
...
0000, count=0
0001, count=1
0010, count=1
0011, count=2
0100, count=1
0101, count=2
0110, count=2
0111, count=3
1000, count=1
1001, count=2
1010, count=2
1011, count=3
1100, count=2
1101, count=3
1110, count=3
1111, count=4
```

So for an even number of 0s and 1s in a 4-bit number:

```
>>> for i in range(16):
...   if i.bit_count() == 2:
...     print(f'{i:04b}')
...
0011
0101
0110
1001
1010
1100
```

Or to simply count them:

```
>>> sum(1 for i in range(2**4) if i.bit_count() == 2)
6
>>> sum(1 for i in range(2**24) if i.bit_count() == 12)
2704156
```

A faster option to count is to generate combinations of N bits taking N/2 at a time, which is ~4x faster than `.bit_count()` summing above for a 24-bit number:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations as C
>>> numbits = 24
>>> target = numbits // 2
>>> sum(1 for c in C(range(numbits), target))
2704156
```

Timing comparison:

```
C:\>py -m timeit -s "from itertools import combinations as C" "sum(1 for c in C(range(24), 12))"
1 loop, best of 5: 383 msec per loop

C:\>py -m timeit "sum(1 for i in range(2**24) if i.bit_count() == 12)"
1 loop, best of 5: 1.53 sec per loop
```

`itertools` solution that generates the bit patterns and values.  for example, below iterates 20 times vs. trying all 64 (2<sup>6</sup>) numbers:

```py
from itertools import combinations as C
numbits = 6
target = numbits // 2
for c in C([1<<n for n in range(numbits)], target):
    value = sum(c)
    print(f'{value:0{numbits}b} {value}')
```

Output:

```
000111 7
001011 11
010011 19
100011 35
001101 13
010101 21
100101 37
011001 25
101001 41
110001 49
001110 14
010110 22
100110 38
011010 26
101010 42
110010 50
011100 28
101100 44
110100 52
111000 56
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing the method bit_count! It performs much, much better. Unfortunately the second proposed solution doesn't work for what I need (I should have explained better sorry) as I need to compare the permutations (abs(sum of values indexed as 1 - sum of values indexed as 0), not just sum every combination. That's why I need a full binary number. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: @am1234 Added an itertools solution that should still be faster to generate the actual values.

Comment: Thanks Mark. The first solution appears to be just as fast, and actually has the added benefit of being able to only generate half the binary numbers (I don't need inverses, see my edit). Thanks to your solution I'm also returning the values as integers, not strings, and using the bits of the integers as indexes (`return [i for i in range(int('1' * (digits - 1), 2)) if i.bit_count() == target]`). This is much faster!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution.

Recall from combinatorics, that the number of unique permutations of N elements across K positions is this:

```
P =     N!
    -----------
      P! (N-P)!
```

For any given binary string of length N, the number of "even strings" where the number of 0's and 1's are the same can be computed similarly as follows:

```
permutations =          N!
               ----------------
                 (N/2)! * (N/2)!
```

Or in python:

```
P = (math.factorial(N) // math.factorial(N//2)) // math.factorial(N//2)
```

Which is simply:

```
P = math.comb(N, N//2)
```

Let's put that to work by by making a decision to append a 0 or 1 on each iteration of the decision tree

**Updated Implementation**

```
import math

def getNumberForIteration(i, length, remaining):
    if (i < 0 or length < remaining or remaining < 0 or length < 0): raise "Error!"
    result = 0
    while (length > remaining) and (length > 0) and (remaining > 0):
        leftCombos = math.comb(length-1,remaining)
        if (i < leftCombos):
            result = result << 1         # append 0
        else:
            result = (result << 1) + 1   # append 1
            remaining = remaining - 1
            i = i - leftCombos
        length = length - 1
    while (remaining > 0):          # pad the end with 1's
        result = (result << 1) + 1   
        remaining = remaining - 1
        length = length - 1
    if (length > 0):                # pad the end with 0's
        result = result << length

    return result

def print_binary_numbers_with_half_the_bits_set(bitLength):
    iterations = math.comb(bitLength, bitLength//2)
    for i in range(0,iterations):
        val = getNumberForIteration(i, bitLength, bitLength//2)
        f = "{0:0" + str(bitLength) + "b}"
        s = f.format(val)
        print(i, s, val)
```

Testing it out (printing the string and its decimal value)

```
>>> print_binary_numbers_with_half_the_bits_set(6)
000111 7
001011 11
001101 13
001110 14
010011 19
010101 21
010110 22
011001 25
011010 26
011100 28
100011 35
100101 37
100110 38
101001 41
101010 42
101100 44
110001 49
110010 50
110100 52
111000 56
```

Comment: This is great! Many thanks. However, it appears to perform much more slowly than the original and other proposed solutions.

Comment: @am1234 - I took the previous feedback about using math.comb and then optimized my original answer to avoid recursion and string concatenation. I would assert it may be slower for small binary strings, but much faster for larger string lengths. Compare `print_binary_numbers_with_half_the_bits_set(24)` with the performance of other answers trying to generate 24 bit strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can start with the following number:

1 + 0 * half + 1 * (half - 1), where half = target length / 2

and then move each 1 from the right half to the left half bit by bit.

Here is the code I came up with:

```
def binary_even(length):
    half = int(length/2)
    result = 0

    for i in range(0, half - 1, 1):
        for j in range(half - i, -1, -1):
            num = int("1"*(i+1) + "0"*j + "1" + "0"*(half-j) + "1"*(half-2-i))
            # Your operations with the number
        
    return result
```

Here *i* is the number of 1's already moved all the way to the left side, *j* is the current position in the initial sequence of 0's.

Sorry if the indexation is confusing, but the code should work and seems optimized to me.

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. This works for a length of four like in the example, but unfortunately doesn't produce all the binary numbers that meet the condition for lengths greater than four.